# ISNUMER excel funtion in PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I have the following dataset

```
sku ids link 
 1   55   1     
 2   56   3     
 3   57   ab    
 5   58   1     
 9   59   bc 
 10  60   1
```

I am trying to define the follow function to create a new column

```
def fmq(row): 
    if row['link'] == 1:
        value = 10
    else:
        row['link']      
return value
```

I am getting the following error 
    TypeError: ("'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'", 
    'occurred at index 0')

```
df['sub_link'] = df.apply(fmq, axis=1)
```

Final Output:

```
sku ids link sub_link
 1   55   1     10
 2   56   3     3
 3   57   ab    ab
 5   58   1     10
 9   59   bc    bc
 10  60   1     10

I know that in excel we can use isnumber([link]) function,
how can i replicate this function in python?
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) + [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html)

Use Pandas methods. In this case, you need to convert to numeric first.

```
link_num = pd.to_numeric(df['link'], errors='coerce')

df['sub_link'] = df['link'].mask(link_num == 1, 10)
```

Row-wise solutions such as `apply` involve Python-level loops: they are inefficient and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you essentially want to test if something is an integer, correct? You can do

1) Casting

```
try:
    to_test = int(value)
except Exception as e:
    pass  # In this case it could not be casted to an int
```

2) type checking

```
if isinstance(value, int):
    #  do thing
else:
    # do other thing
```